# Office VSTO addin Certification

Tags: ms-office, vsto, windows

Standalone Windows applications can be submitted for certification to Microsoft as described on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt637086(v=vs.85).aspx).

How about VSTO addins? Is there a way we can certify these? It would be great for us to "rubber stamp" our addins with the certification logos as it would give some of our customers that little bit of extra reassurance and confidence in the quality of our product.